# Update.forceignore for Spring 21 Compliance

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

SFDX is giving me this error message:
Fix the following lines in your .forceignore and add '# .forceignore v2' to your
.forceignore file to switch to the new behavior.
(node:12432) Warning:   **settings

I looked at the [Sample Apps](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/.forceignore) but they all seem to have the same format I am using (maybe they get updated when Spring 21 goes live?)

But does anyone know what the new format for **settings needs to not throw that warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are in the process of making the change and there is an open [PR](https://github.com/trailheadapps/visualforce-to-lwc/pull/118/files) here to show you what you need to do.

You will need to follow a pattern very similar to the `.gitignore` [format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Hence for your settings file, it will be as below, make sure to use `# .forceignore v2` at the top of the file

```
# .forceignore v2

**/settings/**
```

In the coming days (#safeharbor) we will upgrade our Sample Apps with this new format.